# Is $\partial \partial H=0$ where H is the Heaviside function?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Is $\partial \partial H=0$ where H is the Heaviside function? In other words, I know that $\partial H=\delta$ but do two partials make it $0$?

Comment: Notice that your question is exactly the same as: I'd the derivative of delta equal to zero? And, in fact, the only distributions with zero derivative are the constant functions.

Answer (score 2):

No, the distributional derivative of $\delta$ is not zero: for any test function $\phi$ we have $$\langle H'', \phi \rangle = \langle \delta', \phi \rangle = -\langle \delta, \phi' \rangle = \phi'(0),$$ which is in general non-zero.

Comment: Can I ask you how I can find the fundamental solution to $\partial u + au=f$ where a is a constant? I know that for Lu=f I want to find E such that LE= $\delta$. I am trying to solve ($\partial +a$)E= $\delta$. I am stuck and I don't know what I am doing wrong...

Comment: You should ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you, I did here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565818/fundamental-solution-to-linear-partial-differential-equation